# Use css syntax or custom class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Bit of a noob so need some real world advice.

I've just been reading an article written by mozilla regarding the use of css selectors.

Basically, they're saying don't use complex selector trees, for instance:

```
.class-a .class-b > .class-c is better expressed as  custom-class-abc
```

Obviously they would because the second option is going to be better for the performance of the browser, but if this is the best solution, then it sort of renders a lot of css basics redundant.

I have a UL containing LI's that contain A's. My first A needs to be treated differently, so I use the following syntax:

```
#footer li:first-child a {}
```

If I was to follow Mozillas best practice, this would be:

```
#footer a.first or #footer .first (after adding a class to the first A element)
```

There is enough to learn as it is, so would appreciate some advice on how this all works in the real world.

Comment: Could you add a link to the article?

Comment: CSS is so fast, even with enormously huge selectors that performance is practically never an issue. The reason to not use complex selectors is that it makes it harder to maintain code.

Comment: "then it sort of renders a lot of css basics redundant" This is why I don't take that article seriously at all.

Comment: If you were to follow Mozilla's best practice *thoroughly*, it wouldn't even be `#footer .first`, it would be `.footer-first`.

Comment: I think that the problem of css performance becomes real when you have a very big and redundant DOM (I imagine a site like github with big files with highlight syntax and line numbers etc. etc).

Comment: It also depends on what browser compatibility you are coding towards - some of the older ones can't handle psuedo classes

Comment: I found this article https://speakerdeck.com/jonrohan/githubs-css-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the article may be out of date to cater for the dumber browsers, but most up to date browsers understand :first-child now. Your example

```
#footer li:first-child a {}
```

is how I rock. ie8 doesn't understand :last-child take note.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is just fine. Having not read the article you mention I would guess they mean to avoid something like

```
html body div.wrapper div.navigation ul.nav li:first-child a.item { }
```

and just do

```
.nav li:first-child a.item
```

This [article](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) gives a little bit more on why fewer selectors are better for performance. Of course there are extremes of everything and mozilla should recommend how to make things as fast as possible but selectors are already extremely fast so in most cases it makes no difference.

On a related note reading up on specificity in css may also help you determine how much you actually need to select. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Also keep in mind the MDN article was originally written for use with XUL styling, as much of Firefox's UI is controlled by CSS. Web pages are much more bloated and unpredictable than XUL themes, so not everything needs to be followed down to the letter (extreme cases, as mentioned). Personally my best advice is to strike a balance and only optimize bottlenecks that you absolutely *can't* ignore.